# Getting error 403 Forbidden when trying to post to Adobe /transientDocuments REST API

Tags: c#, rest, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am trying to make a POST request to the Adobe /transientDocuments REST API with a pdf file attached, in order to retrieve the transientDocumentID back for use with other Adobe Acrobat Sign services.

I have successfully managed to implement the Oauth flow which returns me a valid bearer token which according to my understanding, I can use to query the transientDocuments endpoint. So, I have built a method that takes in a pdf file as input to achieve this, but I am getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to complete the request. And when I debug the method and use the bearer token I receive there in the Acrobat Sign REST API Version 6 Methods here: https://secure.na4.adobesign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/transientDocuments/createTransient, the request works successfully. So, I am not sure if it is perhaps an issue with how I am adding the file in as form data or if there might be a complication on the configuration side in my Adobe application settings, I have allowed all scopes there so not sure what else the issue could be.

This is the C# code I am using to perform the POST method:

```
public static string UploadTransientDocument(FileData data, string code)
    {
        string token = adobeOuath(code);

        string base64;
        string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(data.file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            data.file.CopyTo(ms);
            var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        }

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        var contents = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));

        var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formContent.Add(contents, "File", fileName);

        var response = client.PostAsync(https://api.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/transientDocuments, formContent);
        var responseBody = response.Result.ToString();

        return responseBody;
    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: @GinaMarano no updates unfortunately. We have put this feature on hold for the moment but I will be sure to update this post once I am looking at it again and come up with a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing line 9 with ...

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: Still getting an error 403, but thanks for the suggestion.